# uipasteboard, Items of the array always returns nsdata

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uipasteboard

I am trying to use uipasteboard for transpiring data between apps, so I am settings an nsarray which is containing strings....when I try to access the array of strings from uipasteboard, return the array containing nsdata all the times.
here is the sample code:

```
UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"pasteboard" create:YES];//create a new PB if does not exists
//make PB persistent. PB will be deleted when its owner application uninstalled
[pb setPersistent:YES];

//save all items in pasteboard
[pb setItems: @[@"str1", @"str2"]];
```

any idea whats wrong in it?

Comment: Please remember to upvote and mark top answer, answers that have helped you. If none of the answers helped you leave a comment on them to add further details or query the issue further

Answer (score 1):

Yes UiPastBoard returns NSData objects. You need to convert this data into objects. Did you even bother to do any research into this ?

There is a blog here which will walk you through the process:

http://thesmythgroup.com/2013/04/02/working-with-uipasteboard-images-and-text/

It shows how to do it with text and images